# How can I pass parameters to a Rake task invocation in a way that works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm using the Seed Dump gem to dump some seed data to `db/seeds.rb`. Except, I need to run a one-line task after I dump these three tables.

The way I invoke `db:seed:dump` is this:

```
zeus rake db:seed:dump MODELS=Standard,Category,Brand
```

So I tried to override this as follows in `lib/tasks/database.rake`:

```
namespace :db do  

  namespace :seed do
    task(:dump_setup => :environment) do
      Rake::Task["db:seed:dump"].invoke(:models => "Standard,Category,Brand")
      puts "did it."
    end
  end

end
```

I have also tried:

```
namespace :db do  

  namespace :seed do
    task(:dump_setup => :environment) do
      Rake::Task["db:seed:dump"].invoke(:models => ['Standard','Category','Brand'])
      puts "did it."
    end
  end

end
```

I just have the "did it" there as a placeholder until I get this working.

That invocation is ***not*** working. It's dumping hundreds of megabytes from my database. Dumping everything.

The work I've done above is based on the most popular answers I have found here. Not sure why it's working.

Comment: Oooh I have a gem that I could publish where you can just dump all from anywhere (irb, wherevs) also, it add's method a dump method to all active record objects so that you can just do Model.dump and it dumps to seeds.rb? Would that be something you might be interested in if I published it?

Comment: That sounds interesting Drew, I think you would have some takers on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> zeus rake db:seed:dump MODELS=Standard,Category,Brand
> ```

`MODELS` is an environment variable. You need to set the environment variable via `ENV` before invoking the dependent task:

```
ENV['MODELS'] = 'Standard,Category,Brand`
```